# WPF: How do I determine which control is clicked inside a Data Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an event in my data grid

```
private void PatientsDataGrid_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Editor();
}
```

but whenever I accidentally double clicked the side scroll bar of the data grid, that event always triggers. so what can I put inside an `If` statement so that whenever I just accidentally double click the scroll bar, it will skip the `Editor();`?

Comment: What do you want to double click? Row in the `DataGrid`?

Comment: Row in a data grid. I don't want the event triggering if I just double click the scroll bar of that data grid

Comment: My assumption is correct - you set `MouseDoubleClick` event handler on the `DataGrid` itself, not the `DataGridRow` ?

Comment: Yeah. U mean I can specifically set it to that? How? can you show me a markup sample =)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `MouseDoubleClick` event handler on the `DataGridRow` level.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" 
                         Handler="PatientsDataGrid_OnMouseDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```